# how to remove space in source text file in ssis

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one text file like

```
Empid   Empname
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

From the above table I want to load in destination table (OLEDB Destination) like
Empid and Empname column are as a seperate columns as well as data also

Could you please help me how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please make a little effort before asking for help, that way it will be easier for us to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Flat File Connection`, and select "Fixed width" format in "General" tab. Then in "Columns" tab you'll be able to set width of every column.

[image]

Comment: Please send me a detailed way...of screen shorts.

Comment: @user2914891 You asked for "deailed way" 3 minutes after my reply. Did at least try anything?